# Application Insights - Application Map of Function reading from service bus queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm playing around with the Application Map feature of Application Insights and I'm struggling to generate what I expected to see.

I have a "Sender" (HTTP Trigger Azure Function) that writes to a Service Bus Queue via a binding, and a "Receiver" (Service Bus Trigger Azure Function) that reads from the same queue.

I was expecting to see an Application Map that is something like:

Sender -> Service Bus -> Receiver

But I'm struggling. The sending bit seems to work out of the box, as I get:

[Image showing Sender -> Service Bus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nouLY.png)

Unfortunately I'm unable to generate an arrow that leaves the Service Bus. I've tried putting the receiver in a separate project to the sender, as well as the receiver using a separate App Insights resource. This latter attempt just gave me two different app insights to read and all I can see if the function being executed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#trace-message-processing suggests it's possible in normal .NET code. But I can't find an equivalent resource for functions.

Is what I'm expecting possible?

Comment: are you using the very latest version of all the Nuget packages for Functions and the bindings?

Comment: Good idea. I've upgraded and now I don't get the Service Bus icon at all.

Comment: Downgrading Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService back to 2.15.0 from 2.18.0 has brought it back.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work if you disable the preview mode in Application Map? If so, it might be because you need to send more than just 1 call at a time. The preview mode requires that you send data for more than 1 minute on a new Application Insights resource. I tried an out-of-the-box solution using C# Script and it looks like correlation should work at least with Service Bus extension version: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 4.2.1 (from the default Functions 2.0 extension bundle).

Comment: Unfortunately not, thank you for the suggestion though. Out of preview the service bus icon disappears and an arrow goes back to itself (same project) or no arrow (different projects).

Comment: The arrow back to itself is actually the expected result for same project. Were you seeing that in preview mode?

Comment: With version 2.18.0 of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService I see no arrows and no service bus icon with Preview turned on or off. With version 2.15.0 of that package in Preview mode I see an arrow to a service bus icon, but nothing from it. With preview mode off, I get the arrow back to itself with no service bus icon.

Comment: Azure Functions should support correlation with Service Bus through Application Insights out of the box. I don't think you need this Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService package. You might want to try integrating Application Insights through the Function app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration without this WorkerService package and without custom instrumentation.

Answer (score 1):

Distributed tracing of Azure ServiceBus was only release in version [v2.21](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.21.0) - you can see the information in the [release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/releases) for beta 2

- [Added support for distributed tracing with Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/pull/2593)

Sorry for all the links, but doesn't make much sense without them.